# How to add a tuple to list that is used as a database?

Tags: haskell

I have these types:

```
type Person = String
type Book = String
type Database = [(Person,Book)]
```

And this function type:

```
borrow :: Database -> Book -> Person -> Database
```

How do I add (Person, Book) to a database?

Comment: Isn't that just `borrow db book person = (book, person) : db`?

Comment: @Jack #nospoilers :(

Comment: Also the signature should really be `Book -> Person -> Database -> Database`.

Comment: I'll add it as an actual answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
borrow db book person = (book, person) : db
```

`:` is the cons operator, which takes an element and adds it to a list. `(book, person)` packs the book and person items into a single tuple. `(book, person) : db` therefore takes the book and person, packs them into a tuple, and adds that tuple to the list `db`.